# mid value of two integers

Tags: java, integer, binary-search

What is the difference between

```
int x = (right + left) / 2;
```

and

```
int x = left + (right - left) / 2;
```

just I got time limit exception in first case and got accepted in second case when doing binary search

Comment: well in first case you can have Integer overflow if right and left are too big, that's why you should use second variant

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand now.

Comment: @MadiSagimbekov just an advice, try to debug these small mistakes by yourself, by checking the values of variables at each iterations.

Comment: This is OJ problem, and I don't know what are the test cases. possibly TLE occured when n = Integer.MAX_VALUE and search element was near to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of your int variables

> right + left (out of integers limit)

is too big and exceeds integers storage limit
 that's why there was an over flow because of the sum, but when you use the difference version the second one

> left + (right - left) (within integers limit)

it suits the calculation and is in favor of the machine.

Answer (score 2):

The int limit(bound) is 2,147,483,647.

Your `right+left` value is out of bound of `int`.
But `left + (right - left) / 2` value is less than `int` bound, so that is why second expression works fine.

if you adding such big numbers, use `long`.